# Dynamically Reading S3 Files with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-5

I am currently working on a Laravel project connected to an Amazon S3 bucket that contains several image files. I'm trying to make a page that will on page load dynamically generate images based on the files in the bucket. I am hoping for it to reflect when an image is added or removed, either from the page or from the bucket itself.

I have tried to look for answers online, but one consistent piece through each of them is the idea that I have/can access the specific file URL. To my understanding I can't guarantee that I will, though I could easily be wrong.

I can provide more information if needed. Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

---

After following everything below, and some additional tinkering, I'm now facing the following error:

> Undefined variable: images (View: C:\...\upload.blade.php

I'll post snippets of my code so far, in order to better show what the possible problem could be:

**(date).create_images_table.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateImagesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('image_path');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('images');
    }
}
```

**Image.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Image extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

**upload.blade.php**

```
....
<form action="{{ url('upload') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="padding-top: 10px;">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <input type="file" name="image" id="fileToUpload">
        <div style="text-align: center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn-default" style="margin-top: 15px;">Upload Image</button>
        </div>
</form>

  @foreach ($images as $image)
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 panel panel-default widget" style="text-align: center; padding: 10px;margin-right: 10px;">
      <div>
        <img src="{{ $image->image_path }}">
      </div>
    </div>
  @endforeach
....
```

**UploadController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Image;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Storage;

class UploadController extends Controller
{

    public function fileUpload(Request $request)
    {
        /*$this->validate($request, [
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        ]);*/

        $imageName = time().'.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $image = $request->file('image');

        $image = Image::make($image);

        $t = Storage::disk('s3')->put($imageName, file_get_contents($image), 'public');
        $imageName = Storage::disk('s3')->url($imageName);

        $image = Image::create(['image_path' => $imageName]);

        $images = Image::all();

        return view('/upload', compact('images'));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm, what I would first do is register all the files present on S3 in your database, then you could return x amount of random pictures from the database and get them from S3.

Plain MySQL query that return 10 random rows from a given table:

```
SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
```

The laravel way:

```
$images = Images::orderByRaw('RAND()')->take(10)->get();
```

Then you could do something like this in your views:

```
@foreach($images as $image)
    <img src="https://xxx.s3.amazonaws.com/{{ $image->path }}">
     // OR
    <img src="{{ $image->s3_url }}">
@endforeach
```

In your database you will have to put the url or the path to the image on S3. When uploading to S3 don't do it directly to s3, create a simple upload page for your images in laravel and store them in the database when the upload is successfull.

Laravel docs about storing files on cloud providers:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem

Some nice tutorials about S3 and Laravel:
https://murze.be/2015/07/upload-large-files-to-s3-using-laravel-5/
https://return-true.com/uploading-directly-to-amazon-s3-from-your-laravel-5-application/

And the official S3 SDK for laravel
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel

EDIT: This package is better maintained than the official SDK: https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem-aws-s3-v3

Putting it all together in a simple avatar upload function

```
public function uploadAvatar(Request $request)     
{         
    $this->validate($request, [             
        'avatar' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',         
    ]);                 

    // Handle the user upload of avatar         
    if($request->hasFile('avatar')){             
        $avatar = $request->file('avatar');             
        $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();            
        $avatar = Image::make($avatar)->resize(300, 300);             
        $avatar = $avatar->stream();   

        //Store to S3
        $res = \Storage::disk('s3')->put('avatars/' . $filename, $avatar->__toString());   

        // Save filename to database          
        $user = Auth::user();             
        $user->avatar = $filename;             
        $user->save();  


        Alert::success('Profiel foto gewijzigd!');             
        return Redirect::back();         

    }   

    Alert::error(trans('messages.whoops'));         
    return Redirect::back();             
}
```

EDIT:

To clarify my answer; the $images variable contains the random selected rows from the database

```
$images = Images::get();
```

This returns all the images in your database, `Images::` refers to the eloquent model you are using, like the user model that is provided in every Laravel install. eg. `User::get();` This returns all the users in the user table.

In order to retrieve all the Images (or users) you will need a image model. You can create this with the following command;

```
php artisan make:model images
```

In your app folder you will now find Images.php, this is the model, here you can specify any relationships that the model has. I will not get into detail here because this can become confusing very fast.

If it still is not 100% clear I suggest looking into some tutorials about Eloquent Models and laravel in general.

the official docs -> https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent

https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch

This link has some very nice and clear tutorials that describe what I mean, from episode 6 he is talking about simple database interactions.

https://laracasts.com/series/advanced-eloquent

This is also a very nice series about eloquent, it is not that hard, but it will take some time to get your head around it

Comment: First, where is the $images variable established? And does it have to contain any randomization in it? Second, you mention storing the images in "the database" rather than to S3 itself, but I can't tell which part of the code addresses that (for the record, I just created a MySQL table "images" containing a single "image" varchar column). Could you possibly clarify?

Comment: @Alexander I've updated my answer, I highly suggest to take a look at the two last links from laracasts, it will take some time to get through all the vids, but it will help you in many ways ;)

Comment: I'm following what you've provided so far, and I'm currently facing a new error. I've updated my question to include code snippets, so that you can better see where the potential problem areas are.

Comment: Scratch that, figured out what the problem was: I was so focused on trying to pass $images after the upload request that I forgot to pass it in on the initial load. Everything's working just fine now. Thank you so much for the help, Illyas. :)